# Webrtc peerconnection error in Android

Tags: android, webrtc, p2p, libjingle

Guys. I need some help with WebRTC. I am developing an Android app that streams from a Service to a AngularJS client using Node.Js and Express as a signaling server. And I am using libjingle packaged by pristine.

Every time I stop the peer from the client it gives me the following error:

```
09-10 01:43:06.161    5935-5935/org.myapp E/rtc﹕ #
# Fatal error in ../../talk/app/webrtc/java/jni/peerconnection_jni.cc, line 956
# Check failed: 0 == (reinterpret_cast<MediaStreamTrackInterface*>(j_p))->Release() (0 vs. 1)
# Unexpected refcount.
#
```

I have absolutely no idea of what's going. I have spoken [with one developer from pristine](http://tech.pristine.io/automated-webrtc-building/) and he said that this error is not really seen frequently.

Did anybody ever run into it?

Comment: did you solve the problem ?? pls help i also have the same problem.

Comment: @manish I ended up changing lib. I am not using webrtc anymore.

Comment: @BrunoSiqueira now which library you are using???

Answer (score 0):

Tracing back: [The call site](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/libjingle/source/talk/app/webrtc/java/jni/peerconnection_jni.cc&l=974) invokes [CHECK_RELEASE](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/libjingle/source/talk/app/webrtc/java/jni/jni_helpers.h&l=50), which verifies that the last reference is being released.  So, it looks like you've got an extra reference to the MediaStreamTrackInterface.